# Обработка except в дочернем процессе пула multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

**Отредактировано в 18:50 по Гринвичу (после диалога в комментариях и спустя 6 часов после публикации вопроса)**

Как в мультипроцессорном приложении узнать об ошибках в дочерних процессах?

**Суть вопроса:**

Если в мультипроцессорном приложении в реализации `Pool()` у дочернего процесса (именно у дочернего) возникает ошибка, информация о ней не передаётся в родительский процесс и дочерний процесс просто завершается, перепрыгнув на следующее задание в pool'е (или останавливается на месте, если от него зависит созданный им другой процесс)

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count

a = ['parent', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'abc', 9]


def numbr(task):
    b = int(task) * int(task)
    print(b)


def job_distributor(task):
    if task == 'parent':
        while True:
            print('Родитель делает ветку без ошибок')
            time.sleep(300)
    elif task != 'parent':
        print('Дочерний процесс идёт выполнять ветку с ошибкой')
        numbr(task)


pool = Pool(2)
pool.map(job_distributor, a)
print(pool)
```

**Пояснения к коду:**

Функция `job_distributor()` выполняет менеджмент работ из Пула. И благодаря этому, первая задача из пула, которая будет выполняться самим родительский процессом получив `'parent'` идёт по ветке `if task == 'parent'` и никогда не напорется на ошибку в `numbr()`. А вот второй процесс (уже дочерний) дойдя до `'abc'` по логике должен вывалиться в ошибку `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'abc'` и он это сделает, только вы об этом не узнаете, так как процесс просто перейдёт на следующее задание не оповестив родителя о случившемся.

Это будет видно по выводу:

```
Родитель делает ветку без ошибок
Дочерний процесс идёт выполнять ветку с ошибкой
4
Дочерний процесс идёт выполнять ветку с ошибкой
9
Дочерний процесс идёт выполнять ветку с ошибкой
16
Дочерний процесс идёт выполнять ветку с ошибкой
25
Дочерний процесс идёт выполнять ветку с ошибкой
36
Дочерний процесс идёт выполнять ветку с ошибкой
49
Дочерний процесс идёт выполнять ветку с ошибкой
64
Дочерний процесс идёт выполнять ветку с ошибкой
Дочерний процесс идёт выполнять ветку с ошибкой
81
```

Между 64 и 81 произошла ошибка `ValueError`, но в выводе информации об этом нет.

**Собственно в этом и вопрос - как узнавать и обрабатывать ошибки в дочерних процессах?**

Comment: Куда добавляли try-except? Вокруг места ошибки или как-то по другому?

Comment: Странно, try/except вокруг pool вообще тоже срабатывает, я попробовал.

Comment: @insolor добавляю вокруг места ошибки, но не работает так

Comment: @CrazyElf ок, попробую

Comment: @insolor отредактировал расположение try except

Comment: `except *** as err:` так а какой `Exception` вы ловите? Может не тот какой-то, который выбрасывается, вот он и не ловится. Попробуйте ловить обобщённый `Exception` например для начала. `except Exception as err:`

Comment: @CrazyElf это я сейчас обобщил, даже если я просто `except:` напишу, это не сработает, родительский будет и дальше работать, а дочерний просто будет висеть

Comment: @AtachiShadow Тогда у вас не исключение значит выкидывается там, а именно что виснет какой-то код.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115382/discussion-between-atachishadow-and-crazyelf).

Comment: @insolor я обновил вопрос уточнив детали, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: @CrazyElf я обновил вопрос уточнив детали, посмотрите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, замечание по терминологии. В операционных системах уже есть отношение между процессами "родитель-потомок" и соответствующие понятия. В этом смысле в примере, который вы привели, есть один родительский процесс - тот в котором выполняется создание пула и `pool.map(job_distributor, a)`. А все остальные процессы - дочерние. Они по отношению друг к другу - братья (англ. siblings). Это все с точки зрения ОС.

То что вы выделяете один из дочерних процессов как-то отдельно (назовем его координатором) - это логика вашей программы и не относится к ОС. В данном случае это важно и является сутью проблемы.

То что исключение возникшее в одном *процессе* не попадает в родительский или другой процесс в пуле это нормальное поведение.

Процессы сами по себе не умеют передавать исключений в принципе. Исключения и их обработка происходит в рамках одного потока в одном процессе. Если вы хотите передать какую-то информацию из одного процесса в другой (например, информацию о том, что возникло исключение, какое именно и где именно), нужно воспользоваться механизмами межпроцессного взаимодействия из `multiprocessing` такими как `multiprocessing.Queue` или `multiprocessing.Pipe`. В случае исключений это означает что, во-первых, нужно это исключение поймать в том потоке того процесса, где оно случилось, а, во-вторых, передать его куда нужно.

`multiprocessing.Pool` уже реализует это, но только от дочернего (в смысле ОС) процесса (грубо говоря из функции которую запускаете в пуле) к родителю (тому коду который запускал).

Самый простой способ исправить вашу программу это сделать, чтобы координатор совпадал с родителем. В этом случае механизм передачи исключений из дочерних процессов в родительский будет обеспечиваться реализацией `Pool`.

Если же вам нужно передавать информацию между процессами в пуле, то это нужно делать вручную. В общих чертах это может выглядеть так.

1. перед запуском процессов создаем `Queue`.
2. передаем ее все процессам
3. обработчики (в вашей терминологии дочерние процессы) перехватывают все исключения и записывают их и дополнительную информацию (что за задача выполнялась, stacktrace и т.д.) в эту очередь.
4. координатор (в вашей терминологии родитель) читает из этой очереди и решает, что с этим делать

Comment: Всё верно, но try/catch вокруг `pool.map` нормально ловит исключение из потока после завершения его работы )

Comment: Для корректировки "родителя" - под родителем я имею ввиду тот процесс, который использовался для запуска скрипта, и который потом участвует в распределении задач pool.map() первым в очереди и к stdout'у которого остаётся подключён текущий терминал.

Comment: И да, я в процессе поиска решения читал про Пайп (парный коннект) и Кью (множественный коннект), но если можно, покажите код-примеры их использования, потому что я пока ещё не вьехал в то, как они испоьзуются

Comment: И если возможно, вариант правильной реализации Пула, когда как вы пишете, эксепты будут обрабатываться как задумано

Answer (score 0):

Если сделать так, то ошибку покажет:

```
def job_distributor(task):
    try:
        if task == 'parent':
            while True:
                print('Родитель делает ветку без ошибок')
                time.sleep(300)
        elif task != 'parent':
            print('Дочерний процесс идёт выполнять ветку с ошибкой')
            numbr(task)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
```

И здесь тоже ошибка поймается:

```
def numbr(task):
    try:
        b = int(task) * int(task)
        print(b)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
```

Вывод в обоих вариантах:

```
...
64
Дочерний процесс идёт выполнять ветку с ошибкой
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'abc'
Дочерний процесс идёт выполнять ветку с ошибкой
81
```

Но при этом `pool.map(job_distributor, a)` в try/catch оборачивать без толку, вот так ничего не поймается:

```
try:
    pool = Pool(2)
    pool.map(job_distributor, a)
    print(pool)
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
```

Вызов `pool.map` у вас ведь не заканчивается просто потому, что "parent" у вас висит в бесконечном цикле `while` в отдельном потоке, а `pool.map` ждёт завершения этого потока. Не делайте так больше, `pool.map` не предназначен для того, чтобы создавать процессы, остающиеся висеть в памяти, для этого есть другие механизмы. Если же убрать бесконечный цикл и уменьшить паузу, то и этот фрагмент кода нормально поймает исключение после завершения выполнения `pool.map`:

```
64
Дочерний процесс идёт выполнять ветку с ошибкой
Дочерний процесс идёт выполнять ветку с ошибкой
81
Дочерний процесс идёт выполнять ветку с ошибкой
1
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'abc'
```

Код я проверял в Google Colab, если что.

P.S. Странно, но перемещение try чуть ниже сразу ловит Exception даже не смотря на бесконечный while и тут же прекращает работу `pool.map`:

```
    pool = Pool(2)
try:
    pool.map(job_distributor, a)
    print(pool)
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
```

Вывод:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'abc'
```

Возможно, это особенности ipython в Google Colab, надо проверять на других интерпретаторах.

Comment: Да, try вокруг pool не работает в обычной версии питона, по крайней мере до его завершения. Это особенность Гугла

Comment: Да, pool.map() я исправлю на "конечный" вариант, собственно я и не хотел его делать бесконечным, просто пока нет кода для его завершения, потому что я пытаюсь исправлять ошибки в исполнении других процессов

Answer (score 0):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()

    with Pool(2) as p:
        fut = {p.apply_async(job_distributor, args=[x]): x for x in a}
        while fut:
            for f in fut.copy():
                try:
                    r = f.get(1)
                except multiprocessing.TimeoutError:
                    continue
                except Exception as e:
                    # raise RuntimeError([fut[f], f]) from e
                    logging.exception(RuntimeError([fut[f], f]))
                else:
                    del fut[f]
```

вывод:

```
ERROR:root:['abc', <multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult object at 0x0000024759E21190>]
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python-3.8.6-amd64\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "E:\SCR\NEW_STAND\ii.py", line 21, in job_distributor
    numbr(task)
  File "E:\SCR\NEW_STAND\ii.py", line 9, in numbr
    b = int(task) * int(task)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'abc'
"""
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/SCR/NEW_STAND/ii.py", line 40, in <module>
    r = f.get(1)
  File "D:\python-3.8.6-amd64\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 771, in get
    raise self._value
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'abc'
ERROR:root:['abc', <multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult object at 0x0000024759E21190>]
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: 
"""
```

Comment: Не могли бы вы описать действия кода? Зачем мы делаете `pool = Pool(2)`. а потом в цикле `while Pool(2)` создаёте новый объект пула?

Comment: pool = Pool(2) ненужен